# While loop not painting new lines with love.graphics.line

Tags: while-loop, lua, program-entry-point, love2d

This piece of code should make a huge grid. I'm trying to make the code efficient so I obviously don't have to keep making lines to form a large grid.

```lua
    -- Grid Vertical
    local gx = 0 
    -- Grid Horizontal
    local gy = 0
    -- Grid Loop
    local g = 0
    while g ~= 100 do
        print("Grid Loop: "..g) -- for testing purposes of the loop
        love.graphics.line( gx, 0, gx, 500)
        love.graphics.setColor( 255, 255, 255 )
        love.graphics.line( 0, gy, 1000, gy)
        love.graphics.setColor( 255, 255, 255)
        local gx=gx+50
        local gy=gy+50
        g=g+1
    end
    end
```

When the program loads it only makes 2 lines at the very top of the GUI. The lines are barely visible but I managed to locate them when changed the line colour to red.

The finished GUI was completely black but I want my screen to look something like this: *http://i.gyazo.com/7913c29776ba2248c07e37f3be9b64a4.png*

Answer (score 2):

remove those local behind gx and gy:

```
-- Grid Vertical
local gx = 0 
-- Grid Horizontal
local gy = 0
-- Grid Loop
local g = 0
while g ~= 100 do
    print("Grid Loop: "..g) -- for testing purposes of the loop
    love.graphics.line( gx, 0, gx, 500)
    love.graphics.setColor( 255, 255, 255 )
    love.graphics.line( 0, gy, 1000, gy)
    love.graphics.setColor( 255, 255, 255)
    gx=gx+50 -- ** there's no need for local
    gy=gy+50 -- ** you have these values before WHILE Loop.
    g=g+1
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back quick! But i have already tried this, and I've tried again. Removing the 'local' from the variable doesn't change anything.

Comment: try printing gx and gy also and monitor see if they are behaving as you wish.
I don't know love.graphics stuff but check the entries. are they in the right order or do you give the function the right ingredient.
and I also don't understand your coordinates completely please check them also.

Comment: I have checked this, the loop is working fine. It's the love.graphics.line that it isn't working. Is there another way of creating a grid? Or am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for the replies by the way, i need all the help i can get :D

Comment: I've checked it all 100 times thanks for the help, the coords are in the correct set position but its not working. I think that it might be setting one line and when the loop repeats its then moving the same line down a bit. I'm not sure how the loop could create a new line but, this is what i think it is doing, i might set the line to a variable and call upon looking at it's coordinates. The coordinate set out is a little strange. x=0, y=0 at the top left with love 2d.